# Issue in treetable expand event jsf primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primfaces3.2 and i am using the component treetable. while expanding the  tree i am trying to collapse all other tree. but expand event is not working for me.

```
xhtml:

<p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{MyBean.onNodeExpand}" update=":form1" /> 

MyBean:

         public void onNodeExpand(NodeExpandEvent event) {
                String id = ((dummyclass) event.getTreeNode().getData()).getID();
                for (TreeNode app : List.getChildren()) {
                    dummyclass d = (dummyclass) app.getData();
                      if (id.equalsIgnoreCase(d.getID())) {
                         app.setExpanded(true);
                    } else 
                         {
                         app.setExpanded(false);
                    }
                }
            }
```

dummyclass is a pojo class which contains all the getters and setters for the treetable.