# Issue in treetable collapse in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.2 and i am using treetable and i am trying to collapse the tree.but it is not get collapsed.i am not using any events.treetable is enclosed with h:form
and i am using layouts
                           Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is poorly elaborated, it's unlikely you'll get an answer. Please post some code of what you are trying to do, as well as any error messages that comes up in JavaScript console or Server console.

Comment: Duplicate of [Issue in treetable expand event jsf primefaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493691/issue-in-treetable-expand-event-jsf-primefaces). Please don't post the same question over and over. Instead, edit and improve the question. If you can't seem to find your previously asked questions back, just click the link behind your nickname in the top bar to get into your user profile, with an overview of all previously asked questions.

Comment: both are different 'Issue in treetable expand event jsf primefaces' in this question i was used events like collapse and expand.But this question i never used any events just i tried to collapse the tree it is not getting collapsed.So i posted as two different issues.